# Column '_id' does not exist SimpleCursorAdapter revisited

Tags: android, sqlite, listactivity, simplecursoradapter

I want to use the SimpleCursorAdapter to fill in my ListActivity, but I'm getting the classic exception because there is no '_id' field in my Cursor.  Unfortunately, this type of query does not provide me with a field that I can use as my _id field being of the form:

```
SELECT DISTINCT room from tblRates WHERE resid='ABC' AND date='2011-10-17'
```

Because of the DISTINCT I can't just add in the _id.  So what do I do short of setting up a custom Adapter?

Btw, I have seen this post already so I do understand why I'm getting the error.  Just wondering how to get an _id in there with the type of query I'm doing:

[Android column '_id' does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT room, 1 _id from tblRates WHERE resid='ABC' AND date='2011-10-17'
```

This will add an _id column with a value of 1 for each row. Also I think sqlite has something like a hidden "rowid" column for each table if you want distinct values for the column instead of a 1.

Comment: That did fix the issue with SimpleCursorAdapter.  I guess I can use the position in onListItemClick rather than the id, so that should work!  Thanks for the easy answer.

Comment: The one danger with this solution is that you don't know if `CursorAdapter` or `SimpleCursorAdapter` is relying upon distinct values. If it is, setting them all to `1` may cause problems, if not today, then perhaps in some future update to the OS. That being said, it's certainly easier than my solution.

Answer (score 3):

> So what do I do short of setting up a custom Adapter?

Besides the custom `Adapter` approach, you could use [`CursorWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorWrapper.html) to add your own `_id` values. Just sequentially number them starting from `1` or something, and don't attempt to use them as actual keys in your database. :-)

---

**UPDATE**

Off the cuff...

Step #1: Create a subclass of `CursorWrapper`.

Step #2: Hang onto the `getColumnCount()` value of the wrapped `Cursor`, here referred to as `N`.

Step #3: Override `getColumnCount()` to return `N+1`.

Step #3: Override `getColumnIndex()` to return `N` as the `_id` column index.

Step #4: Override all other methods that take `int columnIndex` as a parameter. If the index is not `N`, delegate the work to the wrapped `Cursor`; otherwise, implement it yourself (or throw a `RuntimeException` if it is impossible or inconvenient and you don't need it). For `getInt()` and `getLong()` implementations (not sure which `CursorAdapter` uses), return some likely unique value (e.g., just use your position via `getPosition()`).

Step #5: Create an instance of your subclass, wrapping your `Cursor` with the `DISTINCT` clause, and hand that to the `CursorAdapter`.

Comment: Interesting, can you give me an example of how that would be done (or a link to an example)?

Comment: @Alan Moore: Hope you'll settle for the implementation notes I added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I will check into this.  I'm giving you an upvote.  Not sure if this is easier than a custom Adapter, but its always nice to know what options are available.

Answer (score 1):

Using method "query" in SQLiteDatabase may help.

For example,

```
SQLiteDatabase db = openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.query(
             "tblRates", 
             new String[] { "_id", "room" }, 
             "resid=? AND date=?", 
             new String[] { "ABC", "2010-10-17" }, 
             "room", 
             null, 
             "room");
SimpleCursorAdapter a = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                           getActivity(), 
                           android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, 
                           c, 
                           new String[] { "room" }, 
                           new int[] { android.R.id.text1 }, 
                           0);
```

Comment: the OP wants Distinct occurrences of room