# Android, bind ListView to SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I have an SQLiteDatabase helper, which returns a cursor with just the name column from a database:

```
public Cursor getNames() {
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] {NAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    return cursor;
}
```

I am trying to bind this cursor to a simple ListView contained in the Layout:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

The java:

```
 Cursor cursor = db.getNames();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter (
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            cursor,
            new String[] {constants.NAME},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
            );

    setListAdapter(adapter);
```

I've followed every tutorial I can find but the app still stops unexpectedly. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong!

Here's the LOGCAT trace, hope thats what you needed:

```
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{george.frost.YourCarbDatabase/com.android.CarbCount.Search}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:314)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.init(CursorAdapter.java:111)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.widget.CursorAdapter.<init>(CursorAdapter.java:90)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter.<init>(ResourceCursorAdapter.java:47)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:84)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at com.android.CarbCount.Search.onCreate(Search.java:42)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace along with the code from startManagingCursor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `startManagingCursor()`-method is deprecated. You should use the [Loader API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) instead. If you're targeting devices with an API-Level lower then 11, you'll want to use the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html).

Since it seams that you simply want to load some data from your SQLiteDatabase, you don't need to create a `ContentProvider` but can extend `Loader`. An example and more information on this can be found here: [CursorLoader usage without ContentProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182485/usage-cursorloader-without-contentprovider)

Also, if your Activity only shows a `ListView`, you might want to switch to a [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), since it makes binding data and getting ID's (for example) easier for you.

---

Since you posted your LogCat:

The problem is, that the `SimpleCursorAdapter`-class needs a column named `_id` to get an ID on every row of data from your Database. More information on that problem can be found here: [Android column '_id' does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist)

Comment: Thank you, I did not know startManagingCursor() method was depreciated. I have extended ListActivity although my layout contains a button at the top and a listview underneath. Yes I just want to load one column of data and display it in the listview

Answer (score 1):

Does ur table contains column with primary key...
  first line of logcat says....

```
12-03 17:18:41.557: E/AndroidRuntime(30413): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{george.frost.YourCarbDatabase/com.android.CarbCount.Search}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

see this....

```
 column '_id' does not exist
```

Comment: Cursor identifies entries by using _id so tables in sqlite must contain this,if u are using sumthing like this....