# How to show 2 database values in ListView?

Tags: android, database, listview

I have 2 activities(`Novamensagem & Mensagenssalva`) in `Novamensagem.java` I have a spinner with contacts values, a EditText and a Save button. I select a contact and write a text and hit save. The TEXT gets saved, and when i open `Mensagenssalva.java` all the TEXTs i write and save is there in a ListView. So i want to know how to the ListView show the name of the contact i selected in the Spinner and then show the message. eg:

```
Person's name
Message i have written.
```

//EDIT//

now the error is: Force to Close the app when i compile it. The code now:

```
 ListView user = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShowContatos);
    //String = simple value ||| String[] = multiple values/columns
    String[] campos = new String[] {"nome", "telefone"};

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    c = db.query( "contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    if(c.getCount() > 0) {
        while(true) {
           list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).toString());
           list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("telefone")).toString());
           if(!c.moveToNext()) break;
        }
    }

     // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
     int[] to = new int[] { R.id.nome_entry, R.id.telefone_entry };

     SimpleCursorAdapter myAdap = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listview, c , campos, to, 0);

     user.setAdapter(myAdap);
```

The LogCat errors:
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mensagem/com.example.mensagem.Contato}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist`
So the thing is, its trying to pull a "_id" from my database, but i dont have a "_id" column/row in it.

Comment: I'm going to suggest this again because you are still doing this the hard way. You need to learn about CursorAdapters. Read this [SimpleCursorAdapter tutorial](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/).

Comment: thanks its really helping me. haha i know it still hard to me but they sometimes teach many things you not gonna use.

Comment: ok, so i followed it but a line in my code says that is deprecated:

`The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(Context, int, Cursor, String[], int[]) is deprecated`

Comment: I assume that you are not using fragments, so you can simply add `, 0` as the last parameter to use the supported [SimpleCursorAdapter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[],%20int%29)

Comment: Ok, thanks check edit in question for new error :x

Comment: If your app crashes you should always post your LogCat errors.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mensagem/com.example.mensagem.Contato}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist` but as you can see in the EDIT code, there is no '_id' mentioned, so i dont know what it is?

Comment: btw i do guess is only this line of the LogCat but if you think is not .. ?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3359414/1267661) talks about this error in detail. You need to have the the [SQLite `ROWID`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) column included in your query. If your table already uses `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` then simply change `campos` in your query to `String[] campos = new String[] {"_id", "nome", "telefone"};` but use another String array for the SimpleCursorAdapter that is only `new String[] {"nome", "telefone"}`

Comment: Right, but  i dont have a `ROWID` in my database. So how should i do mine? Then i added: `"_id"` to the `String[] campos = new String[] {"_id", "nome", "telefone"};` but still doens't work

Comment: You should alter the table to add the column, but how to do that is out of the scope of this question. However the SQLite link I provided describes how _every_ SQLite table has a integer primary key if no other key was provided. Maybe this will work for you `String[] campos = new String[] {"rowid as _id", "nome", "telefone"};`

Comment: ok, so i tried the code you provided but, still force to close application, LogCat: `column 'rowid as _id' does not exist`

Comment: ins't all of this problem in my Cursor? is it right? c.moveToFirst... ?

Comment: it Worked :D i did what you said, `String[] campos = new String[] {"rowid as _id", "nome", "telefone"};` and `new String[] {"nome", "telefone"}` for the SimpleCursorAdapter., post it as answer so i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Posted from comments**

You will have more control over your app while writing less lines of code by using a SimpleCursorAdapter as we discussed.

In order to use any CursorAdapter, your table *must* have a `_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` column, which you don't have. While I still recommend altering your table to add this column, there is a quick fix. If you don't specify a primary key all SQLite tables create an integer primary key by default, you can reference it with `rowid`, `oid` or `_rowid_`. But Android requires that the integer primary key column is named `_id`... Simply create an alias with the keyword `AS` for the meantime:

```
String[] campos = new String[] {"rowid as _id", "nome", "telefone"};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create customAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter. Check out this link http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/