# column '0' does not exist for ContentProvider SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am getting the error shown below, how do I fix this problem?

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '0' does not exist
 com.example.contentproviderexample.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:62)
```

the stack trace shows the error exists on line 62 of onLoadFinished method of MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor); // <-- stacktrace error
}
```

here is the code from the ProviderExample class that extends ContentProvider

```
  public class ProviderExample extends ContentProvider {

 public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "notes.db";
 public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 public static final String TABLE_NAME = "notes";
 public static final String AUTHORITY =  "com.example.contentproviderexample.providerexample";
 public static final UriMatcher sUriMatcher;
 private static final int NOTES = 1;
 private static final int NOTES_ID = 2;
 private static HashMap<String, String> notesProjectionMap;

 static {
    sUriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_NAME, NOTES);
    sUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, TABLE_NAME + "/#", NOTES_ID);
 }

  public static interface NoteItems extends BaseColumns {

    // notes in the CONTENT_URI is often plural where the actual table name is often singular version of this word
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY + "/notes");
    public static final String _ID = "_id";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String TEXT = "text";
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + "/vnd.example.providerexample";
    // static final String SINGLE_RECORD = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.example.providerexample";
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + "/vnd.example.providerexample";
    // static final String MULTIPLE_RECORDS = "vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.example.providerexample"; 
    public static final String[] PROJECTION_ALL = {_ID, TITLE, TEXT};
    public static final String SORT_ORDER_DEFAULT = TITLE + " ASC";

  }

  private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

 DatabaseHelper(Context context){
     super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
 }

 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + NoteItems._ID + "  INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +  
         NoteItems.TITLE + " TEXT, " + NoteItems.TEXT + " TEXT);");
 }

 @Override
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int previousVersion, int newVersion) {
 db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
 onCreate(db);
 }

 }

 private DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

 @Override
 public boolean onCreate() {
dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
return true;
 }

 @Override
 public String getType(Uri uri) {
switch (sUriMatcher.match(uri)){
    case NOTES:
        return NoteItems.CONTENT_TYPE;
    case NOTES_ID:
        return NoteItems.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE;
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI" + uri);
}

}
```

here is the MainActivity class

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter;
private LoaderManager loaderManager;
private CursorLoader cursorLoader;
private ListView listView;
private int primaryKey;
private String primaryKeyString;
private String testTitle;
private String testText;
private static final int LOADER_ID = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    primaryKey = 0;
    testTitle = "test title";
    testText = "test text";

    ProviderExample providerExample = new ProviderExample();

    primaryKeyString = String.valueOf(primaryKey);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout, null,
            new String[]{primaryKeyString, testTitle, testText}, new int[]{R.id.textView1, R.id.textView2, R.id.textView3},
            Adapter.NO_SELECTION);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    // load database with test values
    //loadDatabase();

} // end oncreate

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    String[] projection = {ProviderExample.NoteItems._ID, ProviderExample.NoteItems.TITLE, ProviderExample.NoteItems.TEXT };
    cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, ProviderExample.NoteItems.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
    return cursorLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    adapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    adapter.swapCursor(null);
}
 }
```

EDIT:

added here is the query method code

```
  @Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    qb.setTables(TABLE_NAME);
    qb.setProjectionMap(notesProjectionMap);
         switch(sUriMatcher.match(uri)){
         case NOTES:
             break;
         case NOTES_ID:
             selection = selection + "_id=" + uri.getLastPathSegment();
             break;
         default:
             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI" + uri);    
         }
         SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor c = qb.query(db, NoteItems.PROJECTION_ALL, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
         c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
         return c;
}
```

Comment: use this one and try it  primaryKey = 1;

Comment: extract database and see what all it contains, that might help you

Comment: tried primaryKey = 1, and did not change result

Comment: Did you clear your data?

Comment: yes, i did the delete data and delete app also

Comment: tried it again after clearing data and deleting the app. and getting the same stacktrace error on the line, adapter.swapCursor(cursor);

Comment: column 0 means _id, but I never used cursorLoader before so I do not think I can be of much help

Comment: You haven't change NoteItems._ID + " ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT yet

Comment: ok, so it probably means that the _id is not being made.  i will look into the database to see what is going on

Comment: i forgot,  i did change it in the project, but in the code I posted in the question i forgot to change it,  as I cut and pasted that from the other question code,  sorry about that.  i will fix that now

Comment: I think there is a conflict between your _ID and the baseColumns _ID, just remove yours

Comment: Just remove public static final String _ID = "_id"; and you do not have to change any other code

Comment: still same problem,  for the record, I also tried some other things like changing the name of NoteItems._ID to BaseColumns._ID and removing  _ID from the parameters of the db.execSQL() method in the onCreate of  DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper class

Comment: You cannot remove the _ID from the CREATE TABLE

Comment: Clean your project to see if it make any difference

Comment: i found this article of a similar problem,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist

Comment: You did not include _id in your query? Whenever you deal with listview your query has to include the column _id

Comment: i am checking the android notepad sample project for comparisons http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html

Comment: what is your query that give you the cursor?

Comment: i added the query code to the question,  at the bottom of the other code

Comment: and in that query method it uses this for projection in query,  public static final String[] PROJECTION_ALL = {_ID, TITLE, TEXT};

Comment: and here is the cursor loader method in the main activity:  @Override
 public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
      //  String[] projection = {ProviderExample.NoteItems._ID, ProviderExample.NoteItems.TITLE, ProviderExample.NoteItems.TEXT };
  String[] projection = {ProviderExample.NoteItems._ID, ProviderExample.NoteItems.TITLE, ProviderExample.NoteItems.TEXT };
        cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, ProviderExample.NoteItems.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
  return cursorLoader;
 }

Comment: Why do you use Adapter.NO_SELECTION?

Comment: http://helpmeco.de/2012/3/using-an-android-cursor-loader-with-a-content-provider  from the tutorial, "The final argument in the SimpleCursorAdapter constructor is a flag for behavior. This example has Adapter.NO_SELECTION. This mean the Cursor will not re-query if the content is changed. You do not want CursorAdapter.FLAG_AUTO_REQUERY as this will make the Cursor requery using the UI thread which is what we avoiding by using a CursorLoader in the first place. The CursorLoader will handle any data changes and then call onLoadFinished so that everything happens in a background thread."

Comment: I do not know where the author get the info but the official document seem to say there are only 2 valid flags or combination of the two. I always use 0. Try 0 see if it makes any difference

Comment: tried both 0 and 1,  and same result

Comment: I have no idea you should repost the question with title like "Cursor loader error column '0' does not exist" and get people who is familiar with cusor loader to help

Comment: that is a good idea,  but first i will try to see if I can learn something from google content provider / cursor loader setup in the Notepad example project in the android sdk  /tools folder.  and I will post another question later.   I am confident that I will figure this out.  thank you for your help.  you have answered multiple questions for me on databases.  that really helped me with understanding  SQLite. a few weeks ago I finally got an understanding of it.   content providers and cursor loaders is the next step.