# The infamous 'no such column _id' for SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

So yeah, I've seen questions about this all over the place, and so have accordingly added an `_id` alias to my query as below:

```
        SimpleCursorAdapter sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            R.layout.activity_contact_list, cursor, new String[] {
                    "rowid _id", DBOps.COL_CATNAME },
            new int[] { R.id.contact_list }, CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);
```

I'm creating my cursor like so:

```
    public Cursor getAllCategories() {
    return mDB.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "rowid _id", COL_ID,
            COL_CATNAME,
            COL_ICONPATH }, null, null, null, null, null);
}
```

`mDB` in the above is a SQLite database.
I've tried changing the string to `rowid as _id`, which also doesn't work. Also apparently there's no need to change my table structure by adding another `_id` column as a few others have noted, so where am I going wrong here?

*Update* - here's the stack trace -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'rowid _id' does not exist
at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.findColumns(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:333)
at android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter.<init>(SimpleCursorAdapter.java:107)
at com.rex.bizcontacts.ContactListFragment.onCreate(ContactListFragment.java:77)
```

Comment: please share the exception.

Comment: Yep, I've added it now.

Comment: first, 'rowid _id' is not a valid name...
maybe 'rowid_id'. and COL_ID = ??

Comment: No, you're not getting the problem. Read the documentation for CursorAdapter where it says you must include an automatically used column called '_id' for it to work. (Or take a look at the other questions similar to this one). If you don't use an alias for _id, it will complain about it even though there isn't such a column to start with.

Comment: This may help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist

Comment: As mentioned in my question, I've already seen all these. I'm using the same syntax and it's not working, so what else has gone wrong?

Comment: you are not using the same syntax, you send a query for rowid of type _id... remove the rowid, send only '_id' and then show us the exception if any..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No, you're not getting the problem.

The comment you are complaining about has the right idea. `rowid _id` is not a valid name. You can tell that by looking at the exception.

You are welcome to try `"rowid AS _id"` instead of `"rowid _id"`. I would recommend `rawQuery()` rather than `query()`, so this can be written more naturally (`"SELECT rowid AS _id, ..."`).

Comment: I've done both, and each time it continues to complain with the same error.

Comment: Let me try with rawQuery..however the problem is with the SimpleCursorAdapter call, which doesn't take a query string.

Comment: @Rex: `AS` is the appropriate syntax, and I know that it works with `rawQuery()`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/Constants https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsROWID

Comment: @Rex: No, the problem is with the `Cursor`.

Comment: Ok, I use 'rowid AS _id' (case sensitive) in the Cursor and it still complains that the column doesn't exist. I switch to a query() from a rawQuery() (what I'd prefer), and there it expects an actual column name, so just passing _id won't work. 'rowid AS _id' is invalid syntax.

Comment: @Rex: See the samples that I linked to.

Comment: Turns out I was using the row alias in the cursor used in SimpleCursorAdapter's constructor..removing that fixed it.