# _id column for CursorAdapter that uses a SQL Union query

Tags: android, listview, cursor, android-cursoradapter

For below tables:

```
create table professor {id varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255) };
create table student {id varchar(255), first_name varchar(255), last_name varchar(255) };
```

Suppose you have below query:

```
select professor.first_name, professor.last_name from professor
union
select student.first_name, student.last_name from student;
```

and suppose you need to use the resulting cursor in a ListView that uses a CursorAdapter. It is stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) that:

> The Cursor must include a column named "_id" or this class will not
>   work. Additionally, using MergeCursor with this class will not work if
>   the merged Cursors have overlapping values in their "_id" columns.

How would you generate a unique `_id` column value of type `long` for each of the rows in the resulting cursor?

Comment: You could extend `BaseAdapter` instead and implement your adapter similarly to `CursorAdapter`, minus the parts that require an `_id`column

Comment: I did a little reading so I understand your question now, however, is there a reason they need to be of type `long`?

Comment: Also, Is it possible for you to rename the `id` to `_id`? If not SQLite creates a hidden `rowid` column you could alias it _id. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist) out. Look at Tim Wu's answer.