# Listview not listing Database values using CursorAdaptor

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter

I am trying to Populate a list from MySQL lite database to a list view. I found some tutorials that a CursorAdaptor is good so that I could update list based on id.

But i tried the tutorials while no data is listed in listview.

I add and Update contents to database as:

```
 {
if(count > 0){
            String earlierQty = mydb.getDataFromList("qty",item.getId(),tabid);
            BigDecimal updatedQty = new BigDecimal(earlierQty).setScale(2).add(new BigDecimal(item.getQty()).setScale(2));
            BigDecimal updatedAmount = setCurrentAmount(item.getId(),updatedQty,tabid);
            total  = setTotalAmount(updatedAmount,new BigDecimal(item.getTax()).setScale(2));
            taxamount = setTaxAmount(updatedAmount,new BigDecimal(item.getTax()).setScale(2));
            mydb.updateARowByProductId(item.getTitle(), "pos", String.valueOf(updatedAmount),String.valueOf(updatedQty),new BigDecimal(item.getUnitPrice()).setScale(2).toString(),item.getDiscount(),String.valueOf(taxamount),item.getQuantityin(),String.valueOf(total),tabid,item.getId());
        }
        else{
            Log.e("PRICE ",item.getUnitPrice());
            total = new BigDecimal(item.getUnitPrice()).setScale(2).multiply(new BigDecimal(item.getTax()).setScale(2).divide(new BigDecimal(100)));
            total = total.add(new BigDecimal(item.getUnitPrice()).setScale(2)).setScale(2);
            taxamount = setTaxAmount(new BigDecimal(item.getUnitPrice()),new BigDecimal(item.getTax()).setScale(2));
            Log.e("taxamount",taxamount.toString());
            mydb.addContact(new ListItem(item.getTitle(), "pos", new BigDecimal(item.getUnitPrice()).setScale(2).toString(),new BigDecimal(item.getQty()).setScale(2).toString(),new BigDecimal(item.getUnitPrice()).setScale(2).toString(),item.getDiscount(),tabid,item.getId(),String.valueOf(taxamount),item.getQuantityin(),total.toString()));
        }
     showList(tabid);
        }
```

My ShowList function is trying to populate the values to list:

```
public void showList(String tab_id){
            Cursor listdata = mydb.getAllCursorTabItems(tab_id);
            try {
                mListAdapter = new ListviewCursorAdapter(getActivity(), listdata);
                mListview.setAdapter(mListAdapter);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            } finally {
                //mListAdapter.changeCursor(listdata);
                //scrollMyListViewToBottom();
                BigDecimal subtotalValue = new BigDecimal(mydb.getProductListAmountSUM(tab_id)).setScale(2);
                BigDecimal discountvalue = new BigDecimal(mydb.getProductListDiscountSUM(tab_id)).setScale(2);
                BigDecimal taxvalue = new BigDecimal(mydb.getProductListAmountTAX(tab_id)).setScale(2);
                BigDecimal totalvalue = new BigDecimal(mydb.getProductListTotalSUM(tab_id)).setScale(2);
                totalvalue = totalvalue.subtract(discountvalue).setScale(2);
               subtotal.setText(subtotalValue+" "+getString(R.string.rs));
               discount.setText(discountvalue+" "+getString(R.string.rs));
               tax.setText(taxvalue.toString()+" "+getString(R.string.rs));
               total.setText(totalvalue.toString()+" "+getString(R.string.rs));
            }
        }
```

my Adapter Class is:

```
    public class ListviewCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
        public ListviewCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            super(context, cursor, 0);
        }

        // The newView method is used to inflate a new view and return it,
        // you don't bind any data to the view at this point.
        @Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
        }

        // The bindView method is used to bind all data to a given view
        // such as setting the text on a TextView.
        @Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            // Find fields to populate in inflated template
            TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
            TextView type = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.type);
            TextView amount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            // Extract properties from cursor


    String text_name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("name"));
        String text_type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"));
        String text_amount = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("amount"));
        String text_qty = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("quantity"));
        String text_unit = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("unit"));
        String text_price = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("price"));
        String text_discount = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("discount"));
        String discription = text_qty + " "+text_unit+ " at " +text_price +"/"+text_unit+" with discount "+text_discount;
        name.setText(text_name);
        type.setText(discription);
        amount.setText(text_amount);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I catched inside the showlist:

ERROR SHOWING IN CATCH:

> E/ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not
>   exist

Comment: Anything happening in that empty `catch` you've got?

Comment: @MikeM. Let me check

Comment: @MikeM. `column '_id' does not exist` is the error!  I created id column as `id` should i have to change that to _id?

Comment: @MikeM. I changed to _id still same error..

Comment: Not necessarily. You could possibly alias it, like is shown for `rowid` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7494398). If it's not too much trouble, though, you might as well rename it.

Comment: If you change your table in your code, you have to clear the database so it can be recreated with the new column names. Either click "Clear data" in your app's page in the device Settings, or uninstall/reinstall your app.

Comment: @MikeM. It worked. But Not listing correct data! when Database updates the row, it doesn't list the updated row contents! Why?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes i got the issue! Thank  you