# column '_id' does not exist. Available columns: [_Id, Product]

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, android-sqlite

it keeps telling me column _id doesn't exist and in my whole code I didn't find the word _id

```
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "LIST";

public static final String _ID = "_Id";
public static final String PRODUCT_NAME = "Product";

static final String DB_NAME = "LIST.DB";

static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

private SQLiteDatabase database;

private static final String CREATE_TABLE = " CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + PRODUCT_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL );";

final String[] from = new String[]
            {DatabaseHelper. _ID , DatabaseHelper. PRODUCT_NAME};

final  int[] to = new int[]
            {R.id._Id , R.id.Product};

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this ,R.layout.viewrecord , c , from , to , 0);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: you will get your an
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist

Comment: I found the word "_Id" on the second line of the code you pasted us: public static final String _ID = "_Id";

Comment: Clean -> Rebuild -> File - Invalidate & Restart.

Comment: this answers will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist

Comment: It's id with small i my Id has capital I

Comment: Column names are often case insensitive (it depends on which DB you are using and your settings)

Comment: Please show the complete stack trace of your error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android column '\_id' does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359414/android-column-id-does-not-exist)