# Populate spinner from sql and make results unique

Tags: java, android, spinner, sqlplus

Hello me again ( sorry )

I'm tiring to populate spinner from sqlitle and it is working fine BUT my table looks like:

_id | Name | Time | ....

_id: is self incremental number always unique
Name: is name of person, repeats on many lines in this table

I want to put in spinner all names from this row but uniq no duplicates. 
how I'm doing it now:

private void updateSpiner(){
        Spinner nameSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinMena);

```
    Cursor nameCursor = db.getNames();
    startManagingCursor(nameCursor);

    String[] from = new String[]{"Name"}; 
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

    SimpleCursorAdapter nameAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, nameCursor, from, to);
            nameSpinner.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
        }
```

here is how I get the data:

```
public Cursor getNames(){
        final String KEY_TITLE = "Name";
        final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        return database.query("plan", new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_TITLE}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }
```

can somebody explain to me why I need to get also _id row for this, I'm still now to Java and I don't see why I need it, except if I don't do it it will complain that there is no _id.

Buts it is not used in first method I get only Names from it... because of _id I can't use in query DISTINCT = true  because it still return all rows as _id is unique for each line..

Could someone help me to wrap my head around it ? I don't want to make separate table or something..

Thanks,
Vlad

Comment: You need Distinct Names from your table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I couldn't get this work with SimpleCursorAdapter, What I had to do was, use ArrayAdapter instead of simplecursoradapter and add DISTINCT clause in the query after removing ID field from the query. Here is link for discussion on [Why _id field required for simplecursor adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192064/about-id-field-in-android-sqlite)

Comment: So I should do something like this ?

When it comes time to attach the data to an adapter, I like to use a table name alias to query the id field as _id. Example: SELECT id _id, msg from message order by id. That way the adapter sees a field called _id and everybody's happy.

Comment: When you use ArrayAdapter instead of SimpleCursorAdapter, you don't need _id. You will just construct the cursor data as array and pass that array to adapter (There is overhead of creating array, but we achieve what we want).

Comment: I see, so only thing I have to change is SimpleCursorAdapter to something like:  ArrayAdapter<String> new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, from );  and get rid of _id in the sql request ?

Comment: Cursor nameCursor = db.getNames();
    startManagingCursor(nameCursor);
//Here Iterate the cursor and get your data and populate String array.
    String[] from = new String[]{"Name"}; 
    int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};

    ArrayAdapter nameAdapter = new ArrayAdapter (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, passThestringarrayconstructedAbove);
            nameSpinner.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
        }

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your table is not *ideally* suited for a Spinner input. You need to normalize your database and create a new table that looks something like `nameId | name`. Then in the "data" table you would have `dataId | nameId | time | ...`.  Then you just load up your Spinner with the data from the new `nameId | name` table.

Comment: hmm yes I was worried that I would have to create another table. well I can try that as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can use DISTINCT in sqlite query: [SELECT manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)