# Table accounts has no column named otherNotes

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Error:

> 07-03 12:29:18.643: E/SQLiteLog(5181): (1) table accounts has no column named otherNotes

Code:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "accountsManager";
private static final String TABLE_ACCOUNTS = "accounts";

private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_USERID = "userId";
private static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
private static final String KEY_LOGINURL = "loginUrl";
private static final String KEY_OTHERNOTES = "otherNotes";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_ACCOUNTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ACCOUNTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_USERID + " TEXT," + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT," + KEY_LOGINURL + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_OTHERNOTES + " TEXT" + ");";
db.execSQL(CREATE_ACCOUNTS_TABLE);
}

public void addAccount(AccountDetails account) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    System.out.println("Hello!");

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, account.getTitle()); // Account Title
    values.put(KEY_USERID, account.getUserId()); // account userid
    values.put(KEY_PASSWORD, account.getPassword()); // account password
    values.put(KEY_LOGINURL, account.getLoginUrl()); // account loginurl
    values.put(KEY_OTHERNOTES, account.getOtherNotes()); // account othernotes
    Log.v("title", KEY_TITLE);

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_ACCOUNTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

When I remove:

```
values.put(KEY_OTHERNOTES, account.getOtherNotes()); // account othernotes
```

I get the same problem with password:

> (1) table accounts has no column named password

Comment: pull out you db and check if the mentioned columns are created in those tables..

Comment: Potentially you are working with an old version of your db. Try going into settings/apps and "clear data" on your app. Alternatively uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: Change the Database version number and run the code again. !!

Comment: Just a side note: your `KEY_ID = "id";` should be `KEY_ID = "_id";`. *an irrelevant suggestion*. some details here at [About “_id” field in Android SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3192064/593709)

Comment: Just un-install the app from device/emulator, and run again.

Comment: Please triple check your syntax. I faced this issue for not giving a space between column name and its type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It seems that you added some columns later in the database. I do agree with Ken Wolf and you should consider uninstalling and re-installing your app. One better approach is, drop and recreate all tables in `onUpdate` method, and increase the db version every time you change the schema.

Comment: Yes, that worked. I went to settings, and cleared all the previous data. It worked perfectly after that. 
Thank you!

Comment: but drop table delete my all the records from db

Comment: @RameshBhati yup. it will delete all records. If you want to keep that data, create one temp table and then after creating your main table as per new schema, insert records there. remember you have to do all this in onUpgrade method.    Maybe you have fixed it yourself by now, just writing here for other's reference.

Comment: @sachingarg i thing, its not proper solution.  You can use onUpgrade methods and add colum here. and onCreate methos also add colum

Answer (score 25):

Well, If you are confindent about syntax for creating table, than it may happen 
when you add new column in your same table, for that...

**1) Unistall from your device and run it again.**

OR

**2) Setting -> app -> ClearData**

OR

**3) Change DATABASE_NAME in your "DatabaseHandler" class**
( I faced same problem. But I suuceed by changing DATABASE_NAME.)

OR

**4) Change DATABASE_VERSION in your "DatabaseHandler" class**
   (If you have added new column than it will upgrade autimatically)

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
```

Comment: you loss your all data

Answer (score 4):

The SQL code looks fine.
I think that you forgot to call `open()` on your database object that you created.

add this methods to you SQL class:

```
private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

public DataBaseMain open() throws SQLException{ 
    // Open the database to make her writeable, must be called before writing 
    // to database

    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){                
    // Closing the database for writing, avoids error.
    ourHelper.close();
}
```

And use when you want to call you DB.

Answer (score 4):

As Benil says in a [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441927/android-sqlite-issue-table-has-no-column-named#comment25337926_17441927), change the database version number and run the code again.

Answer (score 3):

Try "Clear Data " of your App from Settings. 
For me this problem was occuring because i was storage data on SD Card and later i added some columns. 
So if you are saving on SD card delete the previous data.

Answer (score 3):

For those who have similar problem and above solution is not worked then check 2 things:

1. Space between column name and data type like

   ```
    COLUMN_NUMBER+" TEXT PRIMARY KEY) not  COLUMN_NUMBER+"TEXT PRIMARY KEY)
   ```
2. The order of column during the creation of table should same as map for data         insertion like

   ```
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(TEST_ID, testId);
   values.put(CLASS_NAME, className);
   values.put(SUBJECT, subject);

   "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + "("
               + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
               + TEST_ID + " INTEGER,"
               + CLASS_NAME + " TEXT,"
               + SUBJECT + " TEXT,"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Here It is your query..TRY this.

```
 String CREATE_ACCOUNTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_ACCOUNTS+"(KEY_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,KEY_TITLE TEXT,KEY_USERID TEXT,KEY_PASSWORD TEXT,KEY_LOGINURL TEXT,KEY_OTHERNOTES TEXT);";
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what changes you made and why?

Comment: KEY_USERID,KEY_PASSWORD etc are string variables already declared . you code make absolutely no sense

Comment: He just put KEY_ID and write constraint in " " ,So we can also give constarint as I show.... He can try this once..I think He done mistake in written his Query.

Comment: Your query will create a table with colum names key_id,key_title etc. But he wants column likes title,id etc

Comment: The SQL query which he has written is fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible if you made a mistake in creation query and then fix it,

So in the file system you have a db, but this db possibly has no such column.

Solution:
in emulator find a db file: data/data/com.somecompany.yourapp/databases/db and remove it, then try again.

It's also possible to open this file in some sql explorer and check if there is that column.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue, as I updated my database table in sqlite with new columns during testing phase.

Besides the answers that were already given above, what I found really useful to update SQLite databases (e.g. after changes) is [ABD  Idea](https://github.com/pbreault/adb-idea/), an AndroidStudio plugin that allows you to:

1. Uninstall App
2. List item
3. Kill App
4. Start App
5. Restart App
6. Clear App Data
7. Clear App Data and Restart

Answer (score 1):

You can just specify the version like this:

```
private static final int VERSION = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

If your sure your codes are OKAY, just try uninstalling the application, then rerun it agian. This solved my issue. Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

the possible solution also (not the best one) to use different version of DB, like:

```
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

 public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

clearing app data from the phone settings worked in my case.
either in the android emulator, you can do the same.

Comment: This is not a correct way, rather a work around. The correct method to achieve is by creating `VERSION` for the database. So I am voting to close this.

Answer (score 0):

**Current code is**

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    val createPWDTable =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tblPassword ($pwdId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,$title TEXT,$email TEXT,$pwd TEXT,$notes TEXT);"
    db!!.execSQL(createPWDTable)
}
```

**Now add colmn *encrypted***

```
override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
    val createPWDTable =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $tblPassword ($pwdId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY autoincrement,$title TEXT,$email TEXT,$pwd TEXT,$encrypted INT,$notes TEXT);"
    db!!.execSQL(createPWDTable)
}

override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    if (newVersion == 2) {
        val query = "ALTER TABLE $tblPassword ADD COLUMN $encrypted INT DEFAULT '0'"
        db!!.execSQL(query)
    } 
}
```

Here if New user then oncreate method directly create table with encrypted value.
if Old user then onUpgrade method has check db version and alter the table

Answer (score -1):

I know i have replie to this question to late but maybe someone can solve her problem with this answer.
You are put some data later in table database so the best solution is to re name your data base name.

Answer (score -2):

In my case there was a query syntax error (need space b/w column name and datatype ..see attached image) in onCreate() method

to resolve it ..
I followed these steps

1. Correct your syntax error
2. change DB version number
3. Clear App data  from settings
4. Uninstall and Run Your app again.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Us7.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97Us7.jpg)

Hope it helps

Answer (score -3):

Uninstall your app and reinstall your app and after that it will work fi