# Android + SQLite - table has no column named

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been seeing some of the questions concerning this topic (like, for example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441927/android-sqlite-issue-table-has-no-column-named)) but I think I had everything ok and I already tried Database name changes, Database version changes, re-building...

This is some of my Helper code:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String CONTACTS_TABLE = "contact";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactlist";

// Column names...
public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_FAMILY_NAME = "family_name";
public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String KEY_ADD_PHONE = "additional_phone";

// ... and a string array of columns.
private static final String[] COLUMNS = {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_FAMILY_NAME, 
KEY_PHONE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_ADD_PHONE};

// Build the SQL query that creates the table.
private static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + CONTACTS_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                KEY_FAMILY_NAME + "TEXT, " +
                KEY_PHONE + "TEXT, " +
                KEY_EMAIL + "TEXT, " +
                KEY_ADDRESS + "TEXT, " +
                KEY_ADD_PHONE + "TEXT);";

public ContactHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    Log.d(TAG, "Construct WordListOpenHelper");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CONTACTS_TABLE_CREATE);
    fillDatabaseWithData(db);
}
```

This is now the insert method:

```
public long insert(Contact newContact) {
    long newId = 0;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_NAME, newContact.contactName);
    values.put(KEY_FAMILY_NAME, newContact.familyName);
    values.put(KEY_PHONE, newContact.contactPhone);
    values.put(KEY_EMAIL, newContact.email);
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, newContact.address);
    values.put(KEY_ADD_PHONE, newContact.additionalPhone);
    try {
        if (mWritableDB == null) {mWritableDB = getWritableDatabase();}
        newId = mWritableDB.insert(CONTACTS_TABLE, null, values);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "INSERT EXCEPTION! " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return newId;
}
```

This is where i call the insert method, after getting all the data from the EditTexts:

```
public void saveNewContact(){
    // Getting contact information
    this.getContactInformation();

    mDB.insert(newContact);

   Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), ContactListActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
table contacts has no column named address

05-11 15:19:31.732 9363-9363/com.example.patricia.contactlist E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting name=Patricia address=UNKNOWN family_name=Vera phone=699999999 email=UNKNOWN additional_phone=UNKNOWN
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named address (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(name,address,family_name,phone,email,additional_phone) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have you tried clearing your apps data?

Comment: I only tried to run it on another emulator, but it also did not work

Comment: Delete your app, clean and rebuild project. Code looks fine.

Comment: I did this just in case too, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are missing spaces in your SQL for table creation:

```
 "CREATE TABLE " + CONTACTS_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_FAMILY_NAME + "TEXT, " +
            KEY_PHONE + "TEXT, " +
            KEY_EMAIL + "TEXT, " +
            KEY_ADDRESS + "TEXT, " +
            KEY_ADD_PHONE + "TEXT);";
```

There will be columns named  "addressTEXT", "phoneTEXT" etc.

Try:

```
 "CREATE TABLE " + CONTACTS_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            KEY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_FAMILY_NAME + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_PHONE + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT, " +
            KEY_ADD_PHONE + " TEXT);";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had declared this in ContactsDB.java

```
public class ContactsDB {
public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME="person_name";
public static final String KEY_CELL="_cell";
```

Actually when storing it via submit I was doing this

```
public long createEntry(String name, String cell)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("KEY_NAME", name);
    cv.put("KEY_CELL", cell);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

whereas I should have done this

```
public long createEntry(String name, String cell)
{
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    cv.put(KEY_CELL, cell);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```