# Android SQLite "0 _id" in the select statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm using the [SQLite-asset-helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) by jgilfelt

I try to look into his sample project and came across this code:

```
    public Cursor getEmployees() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {"0 _id", "FirstName", "LastName"}; 
    String sqlTables = "Employees";

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;

}
```

What's the meaning of "0" in that select statement for _ID field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is returning the value of `0` with the column name `_id` (it's using column name alias).

You can return a column that doesn't exist in your table this way.

Comment: Yeah I noticed there is no column _id in the table.So if I print the value of _id, it would just return 0 all the time, right?

Comment: As for **_id**, i'd use **rowid _id**, so it would return the REAL row id (which is a HIDDEN column in every SQLite table), instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Some Android adapters require you to always have an _id field selected even if your table doesn't have one. Try it, your app will crash without selecting an _id. So they are doing a workaround for this by selecting a mock _id value that has 0 in it.

**EDIT:** A better way to do this would be for example if you want to use "id" instead of "_id" in your tables, just do a `SELECT id as _id FROM ...`

Comment: This is not true. I have just tried it, at least on 4.4 it works with returning a single column with any name, e.g. `{"2 aaa"}`.

Comment: This depends on what adapter you are using. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192064/about-id-field-in-android-sqlite

Comment: The code in question has a link at the top, that code uses the Cursor in a SimpleCursorAdapter.