# ListView not showing Data from database(SQLite)

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

I am new to android development so this may seem like an obvious question but I can't figure it out. I am trying to populate a list view with data stored in a SQLite database. I have managed to populate the database.k However, I can't figure out why the data is not showing up in the list view. My code runs fine with no errors. Can someone please help me out. I will truly appreciate it!

**ActivityMain.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_gravity="top|end"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_input_24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/fab1"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:background="@color/whiteTrans" app:backgroundTint="#aaaaaa"/>
    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/mainClientList"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**item_clients**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/edt_client"
            android:tint="#898989"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_black_24dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clientTxtId"
            android:text="@string/test_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clientTxtName"
            android:text="@string/test_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/clientTxtAddress"
            android:text="@string/test_address"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"/>
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dlt_client"
            android:tint="#898989"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
            android:layout_marginStart="70dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AddorEditclients**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".Add_or_Edit_Clients">
        <EditText

                android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
                android:id="@+id/customer_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="@string/customer_name"/>
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/customer_address"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="@string/customer_address"/>
        <Button
                android:text="@string/add"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="310dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="161dp"
                android:id="@+id/btn_add"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Const.kt**

```
package com.abc.clientsapp

object Const {
    public val ADD = "add"
    public val UPDATE = "update"
    public val WHAT = "what"
    public val DATABASE_NAME = "Client_Database"
    public val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
    public val CLIENT_KEY = "client_key"
}
```

**Client.kt**

```
package com.abc.clientsapp

import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable
class Client :Parcelable {
    var id:Int = 0
    var name:String =""
    var address:String = ""
    constructor()
    constructor(id:Int,name:String,address: String)
    {
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.address = address
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "client_Table(id = '$id', name='$name', address = '$address')"
    }
    protected constructor(`in`: Parcel)  {
        id = `in`.readInt()
        name = `in`.readString()!!
        address = `in`.readString()!!
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeInt(id)
        parcel.writeString(name)
        parcel.writeString(address)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Client> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Client {
            return Client(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Client?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHelper.kt**

```
package com.abc.clientsapp.Database

import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.database.Cursor
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper
import com.abc.clientsapp.Client
import com.abc.clientsapp.Const.DATABASE_NAME
import com.abc.clientsapp.Const.DATABASE_VERSION
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class DatabaseHelper(context: Context?, name: String?, factory: SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory?, version: Int) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, factory, version) {
    val CLIENT_TABLE : String = "client_Table"
    val CLIENT_ID : String = "id"
    val CLIENT_NAME : String = "name"
    val CLIENT_ADDRESS : String = "address"
    companion object{
                        private var instance : DatabaseHelper? = null
                        fun getinstnce(ctx:Context):DatabaseHelper
                        {
                            if (instance==null)
                            {
                                instance = DatabaseHelper(ctx, DATABASE_NAME,null, DATABASE_VERSION)
                            }
                            return instance!!
                }
    }
    val createsql : String = "create table $CLIENT_TABLE($CLIENT_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $CLIENT_NAME TEXT , $CLIENT_ADDRESS TEXT)"
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {
        db?.execSQL(createsql)
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        db!!.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $CLIENT_TABLE")
        onCreate(db)
    }
    fun addclient(name: String?,address:String?):Long
    {
        val values= ContentValues()
        values.put(CLIENT_NAME,name)
        values.put(CLIENT_ADDRESS,address)
        return this.writableDatabase.insert(CLIENT_TABLE,null,values)
    }
    fun updateclient(id:Int?,name: String?,address:String?):Int
    {
        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(CLIENT_NAME,name)
        values.put(CLIENT_ADDRESS,address)
        return this.writableDatabase.update(CLIENT_TABLE,values,"$CLIENT_ID=?", arrayOf("$id"))
    }
    fun deleteclient(id: Int?):Int
    {
        return this.writableDatabase.delete(CLIENT_TABLE,"$CLIENT_ID=?", arrayOf("$id"))
    }
    fun getallclients() :ArrayList<Client>
    {
        var list: ArrayList<Client> = ArrayList()
        var cursor:Cursor = this.writableDatabase.query(CLIENT_TABLE, arrayOf(CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_NAME,CLIENT_ADDRESS),null,null,null,null,null)
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {
                var cl = Client()
                cl.id = cursor.getInt(0)
                cl.name = cursor.getString(1)
                cl.address = cursor.getString(2)
                list.add(cl)
            }while (cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        this.writableDatabase.close()
        return list
    }
}
```

**Add or edit clients.kt**

```
package com.abc.clientsapp

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.abc.clientsapp.Database.DatabaseHelper
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Toast
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add_or__edit__clients.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_clients.*

class Add_or_Edit_Clients : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_or__edit__clients)
        if (intent.getStringExtra(Const.WHAT).equals(Const.ADD)){
            btn_add.text = "ADD"
        }
        else{
            btn_add.text = "UPDATE"
            var cli : Client = intent.getParcelableExtra(Const.CLIENT_KEY)
            clientTxtName.setText(cli.name)
            clientTxtAddress.setText(cli.address)
        }
        btn_add.setOnClickListener{
            if (intent.getStringExtra(Const.WHAT) == Const.ADD)
            {
                addclient()
                finish()
            }
            else {
                updateclient(intent.getParcelableExtra(Const.CLIENT_KEY))
            }
        }

    }
    fun logmsg(msg:String)
    {
        Log.d("TAG",msg)
    }
    fun validateinput():Boolean
    {
        if (clientTxtName?.text.toString().trim().equals("")||clientTxtAddress?.text.toString().trim().equals(""))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please Fill all the Fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            return false
        }
        else
            return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        if(item!=null)
        {
            when(item.itemId)
            {
                android.R.id.home->finish()
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
    fun addclient()
    {
        if(validateinput())
        {
            DatabaseHelper.getinstnce(this).addclient(clientTxtName.text.toString(),clientTxtAddress.text.toString())
        }
    }
    fun updateclient(client: Client)
    {
        if(validateinput())
        {
            DatabaseHelper.getinstnce(this).updateclient(client.id,client.name,client.address)
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
package com.abc.clientsapp

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import com.abc.clientsapp.Const.WHAT
import com.abc.clientsapp.Const.ADD
import com.abc.clientsapp.Database.DatabaseHelper
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        var adapter = ClientAdapter(this@MainActivity)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        mainClientList.adapter = adapter
        fab1.setOnClickListener {
            var intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,Add_or_Edit_Clients::class.java)
            intent.putExtra(WHAT,ADD)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
    class ClientAdapter() : BaseAdapter() {
        private var list:ArrayList<Client> ?= null
        private var context:Context? = null
        constructor(context: Context?) : this()
        {
            this.list = DatabaseHelper.getinstnce(context!!).getallclients()
            this.context = context
        }
        fun updatelist() {
            this.list = DatabaseHelper.getinstnce(context!!).getallclients()
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        override fun getView(position: Int, view: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
            var convertView : View? = view
            if (convertView == null){
            convertView = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_clients, null)}
            var txtId : TextView = convertView?.findViewById(R.id.clientTxtId) as TextView
            var txtName : TextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.clientTxtName) as TextView
            var txtAddress : TextView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.clientTxtAddress) as TextView
            var imgEdt: ImageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.edt_client) as ImageView
            var imgDlt: ImageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.dlt_client) as ImageView
            txtId.text = list?.get(position)?.id.toString()
            txtName.text = list?.get(position)?.name
            txtAddress.text = list?.get(position)?.address
            imgEdt.setOnClickListener {

                var intent = Intent(context, Add_or_Edit_Clients::class.java)
                intent.putExtra(Const.WHAT, Const.UPDATE)
                intent.putExtra(Const.CLIENT_KEY, (list?.get(position)) as Parcelable)
                context?.startActivity(intent)

            }
            imgDlt.setOnClickListener {

                DatabaseHelper.getinstnce(context!!).deleteclient(list?.get(position)?.id)
                list?.removeAt(position)
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
            return convertView
        }
        override fun getItem(position: Int): Client? {
            return list?.get(position)
        }

        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return list!!.size
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLite Data Adapter not displaying data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516848/sqlite-data-adapter-not-displaying-data)

Comment: Impossible to say what the issue is as the only **ListView** in the provided code is in **ActivityMain.XML**, that itself only coded the once, and thus most probably used by **MainActivity** who's code has not been provided.